# objective c play audio as it is downloading

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone design question regarding downloading and playing an audio file.  Thanks to Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer sample I can stream audio and play it back, bu that does not save it locally on the phone for later.  Using an NSURLConnection I can download and save the audio files, but I have to wait until I have downloaded them to init my AVAudioPlayer given the data property is read only.  I can not add to the buffer.

My question is how can I start the download, but then start playing the file after "enough" of it is downloaded, but before it is finished?  Is there another audio player other then AVAudioPlayer that I can feed data into as it is being downloaded.

The only way I can see to do it now would be to do both in different threads, but then of course I would be pulling down the data twice.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could do it with AVAudioPlayer but I havent tested it.  I believe I have played audio without it loading fully with AVPlayer like so:

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:assetUrl];   
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an AVAudioSession along with a MPMoviePlayerViewController.

```
/**
 * Play audio session
 *
 * @version $Revision: 0.1
 */
- (void)playAudioWithURL:(NSString *)audioURL {

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];

    if (setCategoryError) {

    }

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];

    if (activationError) { 

    }

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *tempPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[audioURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

    // Make sure we have airplay
    if([tempPlayer.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)]) {
        tempPlayer.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    }

    tempPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    tempPlayer.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:tempPlayer];
    [tempPlayer.moviePlayer play];
    [tempPlayer release];

}//end
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your suggestions, but neither save the audio file to replay later.  I would like to save them so I could play them while not connected. I can do this, but I can not find a way to start the playing of the file as it is downloaded.  I can stream it, which starts within 5-7 seconds, but does not save it locally.  I can save it locally then play, but that requires the user to wait until the whole thing is downloaded before you can start playing it.