# AVAudioPlayer do not play AMR files

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, amr

I ad using below code to download an AMR file from web and playing by `AVAudioPlayer` but all times I get the `unrecongnize selector sent to instance` error.

This is the method that start download and play:

```
- (IBAction)DisplayAudioPlayView:(id)sender 
{    
    [self InitializePlayer];   
}

-(void) InitializePlayer
{
    // Get the file path to the doa audio to play.
    NSString *filePath = [[ServerInteraction instance] getAudio:audioData.ID];

    // Convert the file path to a URL.
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: filePath];

    //Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
    audioPlayer=  [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL] ;
    audioPlayer.delegate= self; //THIS LINE CAUSE ERROR//

    // Preloads the buffer and prepares the audio for playing.
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;

    [audioPlayer play]
}
```

**Edit**

Based on @Michael advise I change my code and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6461544/1939409) I changed my code to this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://www.domain1.com/mysound.mp3"];

//Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
audioPlayer=  [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Now it played the sound but when I use `http://maindomain.com/mysound.amr` it is not playing the sound.

Comment: Don't confuse `AVAudioPlayer` with `AVPlayer`! The latter one has no setter method for `delegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following points:

- AMR is no longer supported (for ≥ iOS 4.3, see [supported audio formats in the Apple iOS SDK Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)).
- Do you want to use the `AVPlayer` (audio and video) or do you want audio only? Use for Audio only the `AVAudioPlayer`. The following code snippet shows how to handle it.
- If you want to use `AVAudioPlayer`, does your self instance implement the [AVAudioPlayerDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/avaudioplayerdelegateprotocolreference/Reference/Reference.html)?
- Does your self instance implement the [AVAudioPlayerDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/avaudioplayerdelegateprotocolreference/Reference/Reference.html)?
- Have you added and linked correctly the AVAudioFoundation framework (`#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`)?

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"m4a"]];

      NSError *error = noErr;
      self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
      if (error)
      {
          NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      }
      else 
      {
          self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
          [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
      }
  }

  - (void)playAudio
  {
      [self.audioPlayer play];
  }
  ```

Comment: AMR is no longer (≥ iOS 4.3) supported.