# How to play an AMR audio file?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play an .amr file.

```
func prepareAudio() {
    do {
        self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("welcome", ofType: "amr")!))
        self.audioPlayer.play()           
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

**outPut**

```
ERROR:    >aq> 327: AudioConverterNew from AudioQueueNew returned 'fmt?'
io:     1 ch,   8000 Hz, Float32
client:    1 ch,   8000 Hz, 'samr' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 2400 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
```

Comment: AMR is no longer supported by AVPlayer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103790/avaudioplayer-do-not-play-amr-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMR codec was removed from iOS in version 3.2 (I think). Ah no, 4.3 (thanks, Eric D.). The only reference I ever found to this was in the [dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/400291#400291) (login required).

The strange thing is, while `kAudioFormatAMR` was removed in iOS 4.3, it looks like `kAudioFormatAMR_WB` was [added to OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/frameworks/CoreAudio.html).

Comment: thanks - I was trying to dig out the reference. odd about wide-band being supported in osx