# want to create an app with .amr audio format file in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

Hello I want to create an audio player app, which contains around 250 songs. App must work offline. So, i tried to use `.aac` and `.mp3` format for audio but the size of the app increased to around `300Mb`.

Now I want want to use `.amr` format but the simulator does not work with the `.amr` format. Need suggestion.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    playList = [
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn01", ofType: "aac")!),
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn02", ofType: "aac")!),
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn01", ofType: "aac")!),
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn04", ofType: "aac")!),
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn05", ofType: "aac")!),
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn06", ofType: "aac")!),
        URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vpn07", ofType: "aac")!)]
```

Comment: AMR is not supported anymore in iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379968/how-to-play-an-amr-audio-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play an AMR audio file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379968/how-to-play-an-amr-audio-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check the following points:
```

AMR is no longer supported (for ≥ iOS 4.3, see supported audio formats in the Apple iOS SDK Documentation).
Do you want to use the AVPlayer (audio and video) or do you want audio only? Use for Audio only the AVAudioPlayer. The following code snippet shows how to handle it.
If you want to use AVAudioPlayer, does your self instance implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate Protocol?
Does your self instance implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate Protocol?
Have you added and linked correctly the AVAudioFoundation framework (#import )?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"m4a"]];

    NSError *error = noErr;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else 
    {
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}

- (void)playAudio
{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```